# ayuda archivos txt en python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Buenas noches

Veran soy nuevo en python y necesito
alguien que me explique como hacer para
guardar en archivo txt una informacion x
por ejemplo:

estudiante : carlos rojas
edad : 29
direccion: alajuela
telefo : 2222222

estudiante: luis perez
edad: 18
direccion: heredia
telefono: 5555555

para luego buscarla en el mismo txt y de ser necesario modificar
 alguna en especifico o borrarla
le agradesco cualquier ayuda que me brinden

Answer (score 3):

Guardar los datos con esa estructura es complicarse la vida inecesariamente a la hora de recuperarlos. La opción de serializar los datos que plantea Gerardo es muy buena si solo vas a leer los datos con Python. Puedes crearte una clase estudiante con los atributos adecuados y serializar las instancias. Otra opción es almacenarlos en un diccionario y luego serializarlo.

No obstante si tienes que usar un archivo de texto lo mejor sería usar un formato tipo [csv](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valores_separados_por_comas). Estudiante, direccion y teléfono serían las columnas:

```
import csv

headers = ('estudiante', 'direccion', 'telefono')
datos=({'estudiante':'Carlos Rojas', 'direccion':'Alajuela', 'telefono':'2222222'},
       {'estudiante':'Luiz Perez', 'direccion':'Heredia', 'telefono':'5555555'})

with open('datos.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=headers)
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(datos)
```

El csv o txt (la extensión da igual en realidad) sería:

> estudiante,direccion,telefono
>   Carlos Rojas,Alajuela,2222222
>   Luiz Perez,Heredia,8888888

Posteriormente podemos recuperar los datos de forma análoga:

```
import csv

with open('datos.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        print(row['estudiante'], row['direccion'],  row['telefono'],)
```

Con lo que obtenemos:

> ('Carlos Rojas', 'Alajuela', '2222222')
>   ('Luiz Perez', 'Heredia', '5555555')

Puedes añadir datos o modificar los fácilmente. Para modificar datos en un fichero de texto generalmente se carga en memoria, se modifican y luego se reescribe:

```
import csv


with open('datos.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    data = [row for row in reader]
    for row in data:
        if row['estudiante']=='Luiz Perez':
            row['telefono']='8888888'

with open('datos.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    nuevo = {'estudiante':'Laura Aguilera', 'direccion':'Alajuela', 'telefono':'9999999'}
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=reader.fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(data)
    writer.writerow(nuevo)
```

Con esto cambiamos el `telefono` de `Luiz Peres` y añadimos otra estudiante llamada 'Laura Aguilera'.

Comment: gracias FJ entendi bien, en realidad tengo que usar los archivos de texto si o si porque es para un proyecto que tengo que hacer dentro de unas semanas

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar el module `pickle` para guardar un objeto completo en un archivo binario

```
pickle.dump(obj, file, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```

y para leer cada objeto usarias

```
obj = pickle.load(file)
```

de esta forma puedes cargar objeto por objeto guardado en el archivo y verificar si es lo que estas buscando por ejemplo

```
if obj.nombre = "nombre":
     # dejas de buscar y procesas la informacion
else:
     #sigues cargando el sig. obj hasta que llegues al final del archivo judicial
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes crear un archivo que tiene los lineas separado con punto y coma como en ejemplo:

```
data = [line.split(';') for line in open('archivo.txt').read().splitlines()]
```

Answer (score 0):

para guardar un archivo con texto primero tienes que abrirlo o crearlo. Eso se hace de la siguiente manera: `archivo = open("archivo.txt","w")` la w indica que quieres sobreescribirlo. Luego, con `archivo.write("texto texto")` sobreescribes cualquier informacion que haya en el archivo. Por último, tienes que cerrarlo: `archivo.close()` cerrarlo cuando está en modo "w" te permitirá abrirlo en modo "r" para leerlo. También puedes abrirlo en modo "r+" para escribirlo y leerlo. Y "a" te permitirá añadir texto al ya existente en el archivo